# Setting up KeyListeners using the MVC in java

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, jframe, keylistener

I am trying to make myself a calculator in Java. I figured it would be best to implement the MVC (model view controller) design for my code. I have some of the basics working, the calculator does actually work, the issue is i cannot figure out where i am going wrong with the implementation of listening to keys. At the moment i have the ability to click on the buttons using the action listener and updating the field with a numeric value and the buttons to add, subtract, multiply, divide and also to clear. So really the only thing on my mind at the moment is trying to allow the user (myself) the option to use the number pad on the keyboard to append values to the field, anyways here is my code.

*This the view*

```
    package Calculator;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class CalcFrame extends JFrame{


    private Dimension d = new Dimension(300,300);
    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    JButton equals = new JButton("=");
    JButton addBtn = new JButton("+");
    JButton subtractBtn = new JButton("-");
    JButton multiplyBtn = new JButton("*");
    JButton divideBtn = new JButton("/");
    JTextArea field = new JTextArea(1,20);
    JButton numBtn[] = new JButton[11];
    String numTxt[] = {"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","C"}; 
    Color newColor = new Color(10,70,40);
    int x = 50, y = 0;
    public CalcFrame(){
        this.setSize(d);
        this.setResizable(false);
    //  frame.setVisible(true);
        this.setTitle("Marks Calculator");
        this.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("emblem.png")).getImage());

        for(int i = 0; i < numBtn.length; i++){
            numBtn[i] = new JButton(numTxt[i]);
            numBtn[i].setSize(50, 30);

        }
        for(int i = 0; i <numBtn.length; i++){
            numBtn[0].setLocation(10,180);
            numBtn[1].setLocation(10,140);
            numBtn[2].setLocation(65,140);
            numBtn[3].setLocation(120,140);
            numBtn[4].setLocation(175,140);
            numBtn[5].setLocation(10,100);
            numBtn[6].setLocation(65,100);
            numBtn[7].setLocation(120,100);
            numBtn[8].setLocation(175,100);
            numBtn[9].setLocation(10,60);
            numBtn[10].setLocation(175,20);
            panel2.add(numBtn[i]);

        }
        field.setLocation(10, 10);
        field.setSize(280,30);
        field.setEditable(false);
        field.setFocusable(true);
        panel1.setSize(300, 50);
        panel1.setLayout(null);
        this.add(panel1);

        panel2.setSize(300, 250);
        panel2.setBackground(newColor);
        panel2.setLocation(0, 51);
        panel2.setLayout(null);
        this.add(panel2);

        equals.setLocation(230,180);
        equals.setSize(50, 30);
        panel2.add(equals);


        addBtn.setLocation(230, 140);
        addBtn.setSize(50,30);      
        panel2.add(addBtn);

        subtractBtn.setLocation(230, 100);
        subtractBtn.setSize(50,30);     
        panel2.add(subtractBtn);

        multiplyBtn.setLocation(230, 60);
        multiplyBtn.setSize(50,30);     
        panel2.add(multiplyBtn);

        divideBtn.setLocation(230, 20);
        divideBtn.setSize(50,30);       
        panel2.add(divideBtn);


        panel1.add(field);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(rootPane);
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    }

    public void addKeyL(KeyListener keyp){
        addKeyListener(keyp);
    }

    public void addListener(ActionListener listener){



    addBtn.addActionListener(listener);
    subtractBtn.addActionListener(listener);
    equals.addActionListener(listener);
    multiplyBtn.addActionListener(listener);
    divideBtn.addActionListener(listener);

    for(int i = 0; i < numBtn.length; i++){
        numBtn[i].addActionListener(listener);
    }



    }

    public int getFieldText(){

        return Integer.parseInt(field.getText());
    }
public void setFieldText(){

        field.setText("");
    }
    public void setAnswer(int solution){

        field.setText(Integer.toString(solution));
    }

}
```

*this is the model*

```
package Calculator;

public class Calculations {

    private int total;

    public void addNumbers(int a, int b){

        total = a + b;
    }

    public void subtractNumbers(int a, int b){

        total = a - b;
    }

    public void multiplyNumbers(int a, int b){

        total = a * b;
    }

    public void divideNumbers(int a, int b){

        total = a / b;
    }
    public int getTotal(){
        return total;
    }

}
```

*and this is the controller*

```
package Calculator;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class KeyEvents{

    private boolean isAdd = false;
    private boolean isSubtract = false;
    private boolean isDivide = false;
    private boolean isMultiply = false;
    private CalcFrame view = new CalcFrame();
    private Calculations model = new Calculations();
    int a = 0, b = 0, answer;
    int counter = 0;
    public KeyEvents(CalcFrame view, Calculations model){
        this.view = view;
        this.model = model;

        this.view.addListener(new CalcListener());
        this.view.addKeyL(new CalcListener());
    }



    class CalcListener implements ActionListener, KeyListener{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                if(e.getSource().equals(view.addBtn)){
                    a = view.getFieldText();
                    view.field.setText("");
                    isAdd = true;
                    isSubtract = false;
                    isDivide = false;
                    isMultiply = false;

                }   


                if(e.getSource().equals(view.numBtn[0])){
                     view.field.append("0");                     
                }

                if(e.getSource().equals(view.numBtn[1])){
                    view.field.append("1");                 
                }

                if(e.getSource().equals(view.numBtn[2])){
                    view.field.append("2");
                }

                if(e.getSource().equals(view.numBtn[3])){
                    view.field.append("3");
                }

                if(e.getSource().equals(view.numBtn[4])){
                    view.field.append("4");
                }

                if(e.getSource().equals(view.numBtn[5])){
                    view.field.append("5");
                }

                if(e.getSource().equals(view.numBtn[6])){
                    view.field.append("6");;
                }

                if(e.getSource().equals(view.numBtn[7])){
                    view.field.append("7");
                }

                if(e.getSource().equals(view.numBtn[8])){
                    view.field.append("8");
                }

                if(e.getSource().equals(view.numBtn[9])){
                    view.field.append("9");
                }
                if(e.getSource().equals(view.numBtn[10])){
                    view.field.setText("");
                }

                if(e.getSource().equals(view.subtractBtn)){
                    a = view.getFieldText();
                    view.field.setText("");
                    isAdd = false;
                    isSubtract = true;
                    isDivide = false;
                    isMultiply = false;
                }   

                if(e.getSource().equals(view.multiplyBtn)){
                    a = view.getFieldText();
                    view.field.setText("");
                    isAdd = false;
                    isSubtract = false;
                    isDivide = false;
                    isMultiply = true;
                }   

                if(e.getSource().equals(view.divideBtn)){
                    a = view.getFieldText();
                    view.field.setText("");
                    isAdd = false;
                    isSubtract = false;
                    isDivide = true;
                    isMultiply = false;
                }   

                if(e.getSource().equals(view.equals)){
                    b = view.getFieldText();

                    if(isAdd == true){
                        view.setFieldText();
                        model.addNumbers(a, b);             
                        view.setAnswer(model.getTotal());
                    }

                    if(isSubtract == true){
                        view.setFieldText();
                        model.subtractNumbers(a, b);
                        view.setAnswer(model.getTotal());
                    }

                    if(isMultiply == true){
                        view.setFieldText();
                        model.multiplyNumbers(a, b);
                        view.setAnswer(model.getTotal());
                    }

                    if(isDivide == true){
                        view.setFieldText();
                        model.divideNumbers(a, b);
                        view.setAnswer(model.getTotal());
                    }

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            if(e.getSource().equals(KeyEvent.VK_0)){
                System.out.println("sjkdhlkj");
            }
            if(e.getSource().equals(KeyEvent.VK_1)){
                view.field.append("1");
            }
            if(e.getSource().equals(KeyEvent.VK_2)){
                view.field.append("2");
            }
            if(e.getSource().equals(KeyEvent.VK_3)){
                view.field.append("3");
            }
            if(e.getSource().equals(KeyEvent.VK_4)){
                view.field.append("4");
            }
            if(e.getSource().equals(KeyEvent.VK_5)){
                view.field.append("5");
            }
            if(e.getSource().equals(KeyEvent.VK_6)){
                view.field.append("6");
            }
            if(e.getSource().equals(KeyEvent.VK_7)){
                view.field.append("7");
            }
            if(e.getSource().equals(KeyEvent.VK_8)){
                view.field.append("8");
            }
            if(e.getSource().equals(KeyEvent.VK_9)){
                view.field.append("9");
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if(e.getSource().equals(KeyEvent.VK_0)){
                System.out.println("sjkdhlkj");
            }
            if(e.getSource().equals(KeyEvent.VK_1)){
                view.field.append("1");
            }
            if(e.getSource().equals(KeyEvent.VK_2)){
                view.field.append("2");
            }
            if(e.getSource().equals(KeyEvent.VK_3)){
                view.field.append("3");
            }
            if(e.getSource().equals(KeyEvent.VK_4)){
                view.field.append("4");
            }
            if(e.getSource().equals(KeyEvent.VK_5)){
                view.field.append("5");
            }
            if(e.getSource().equals(KeyEvent.VK_6)){
                view.field.append("6");
            }
            if(e.getSource().equals(KeyEvent.VK_7)){
                view.field.append("7");
            }
            if(e.getSource().equals(KeyEvent.VK_8)){
                view.field.append("8");
            }
            if(e.getSource().equals(KeyEvent.VK_9)){
                view.field.append("9");
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            if(e.getSource().equals(KeyEvent.VK_0)){
                System.out.println("sjkdhlkj");
            }
            if(e.getSource().equals(KeyEvent.VK_1)){
                view.field.append("1");
            }
            if(e.getSource().equals(KeyEvent.VK_2)){
                view.field.append("2");
            }
            if(e.getSource().equals(KeyEvent.VK_3)){
                view.field.append("3");
            }
            if(e.getSource().equals(KeyEvent.VK_4)){
                view.field.append("4");
            }
            if(e.getSource().equals(KeyEvent.VK_5)){
                view.field.append("5");
            }
            if(e.getSource().equals(KeyEvent.VK_6)){
                view.field.append("6");
            }
            if(e.getSource().equals(KeyEvent.VK_7)){
                view.field.append("7");
            }
            if(e.getSource().equals(KeyEvent.VK_8)){
                view.field.append("8");
            }
            if(e.getSource().equals(KeyEvent.VK_9)){
                view.field.append("9");
            }           
        }
    }   
}
```

the tl;dr of this is, i am unable to get keyListener to work correctly, i have tried assigning the keyListener to the field, panel1, panel2 and this.  seperately. Assistance is appreciated as always.

~UPDATE~
I decided to give GitHub a try and have just put my code up on to it. I hope it would make my code easier to understand or even forkable so a person can mess around with it.
https://github.com/niroshido/TestCalculator/tree/master/Calculator

Comment: What happens if you step it through a debugger? Does it enter i.e. the keyPressed? What if you move the "System.out.println("sjkdhlkj");" out of the if-case?

Comment: Hi Stevie, i copied the System.out. out of the if block, it does work from that perspective. In my attempt to debug the following happened (i set up my breakpoint at   if(e.getSource().equals(KeyEvent.VK_0)){
                System.out.println("sjkdhlkj");
            }). It goes to Integer.valueOf and the checks if it equals then it exists that goes to next if statement

Comment: don't use keylisteners at all

Comment: kleopatra, are you suggesting that i simply get rid of the keylisteners implementation and make the textArea editable and have a try-catch block to stop non-numeric values type in?

Comment: @tommyknocker, kleopatra is suggesting you use Key Bindings. Swing was designed to be used this way. All Swing components use Key Bindings to handle keyboard events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html). A simple example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class CalculatorPanel extends JPanel
{
    private JTextField display;

    public CalculatorPanel()
    {
        Action numberAction = new AbstractAction()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                display.setCaretPosition( display.getDocument().getLength() );
                display.replaceSelection(e.getActionCommand());
            }
        };

        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

        display = new JTextField();
        display.setEditable( false );
        display.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
        add(display, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setLayout( new GridLayout(0, 5) );
        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            String text = String.valueOf(i);
            JButton button = new JButton( text );
            button.addActionListener( numberAction );
            button.setBorder( new LineBorder(Color.BLACK) );
            button.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(50, 50) );
            buttonPanel.add( button );

            KeyStroke pressed = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(text);
            InputMap inputMap = button.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            inputMap.put(pressed, text);
            button.getActionMap().put(text, numberAction);
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
//      UIManager.put("Button.margin", new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10) );

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Calculator Panel");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.add( new CalculatorPanel() );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You either need to make sure that whatever component you're adding the KeyListener to has the focus, or you should use key bindings instead.

Comment: yeah i set this.setFocusable(true); for the JFrame, no change

Comment: That's not enough. What's happening is that the buttons and other components have the focus, not the JFrame. You either have to transfer the focus back to the JFrame, make the components not focusable, add the KeyListener to every single component, or use key bindings.