# ActionListener finds the proper name (not string that appears) of pressed JButton?

Tags: java, swing, button, if-statement, jbutton

I have encountered a problem I can't find the solution for, in Java revolving around JButtons.

As I want to keep my code 'cleaner', I have declared all my buttons using the following `for` loop:

```
JButton[] buttons= new JButton[10];
for(int i = 0;i < buttons.length;i++){
    buttons[i] = new JButton("Example "+i);
    contents2.add(buttons[i]);
    buttons[i].addActionListener(listener);}
```

And the actionListener `listener` is as follows:

```
ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            if(actionEvent.getSource() == (JButton)buttons[1].getSource()){
                System.out.println("Test");
            }
        }
    };
```

However then `buttons` in `if(actionEvent.getSource() == (JButton)buttons[1].getSource())` has Eclipse tell me Buttons cannot be resolved to a variable.

In that same line, I've also tried without the `(JButton)`, without the `.getSource()` after `buttons[1]`, and more combinations.

I have confused myself, however I simply want the action performed in the `listener` to happen if the button pressed was **_**.

Sorry for the confusion, but if you understand this, any help would be appreciated. I just keep getting strings other than what I desire.

Comment: There are a number of issues that could be causing this, but without more context is difficult to know which one(s) are you are suffering from.  Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem, this will reduce the guess work and produce better response

Comment: `As I want to keep my code 'cleaner',` - then you should not have if/else (or switch) statements in the ActionListener. If the buttons have similar functionality then you should do something like the example in [Calculator Panel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21434873/setting-up-keylisteners-using-the-mvc-in-java/21436635#21436635). If the functionality can't be made generic, then you should create separate ActionListeners.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using source which does not exist, you can use the `setActionCommand` method to be used in your action listener.

**sample:**

```
ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            String index = actionEvent.getActionCommand();

            switch(Integer.valueOf(index)){
                case 1: //your actions here for index 1 of button
                break;
            }
        }
    };

final JButton[] buttons= new JButton[10];
    for(int i = 0;i < buttons.length;i++){
        buttons[i] = new JButton("Example "+i);
        contents2.add(buttons[i]);
        buttons[i].setActionCommand(i+"");
        buttons[i].addActionListener(listener);
    }
```

As you could see the `action command` is the index of your button so you could use the switch statement for performing actions on each of your buttons.

`case 1` means the `index 1` of your `Button` array.

Comment: So instead of providing a cleaner solution, we've introduced a more inefficient solution instead.  Also, Java 7 allows you to use `String` in `switch` statements

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes you are right switch statement allows string but it slower vs integer, because it will itearate to each of the case statement using the equals method vs integer that will use hashtable with the speed of O(1)

Comment: @MadProgrammer 10 instances?? no it is just one, what I am trying to do is to create one instance and use the case statement for each of the buttons that will use the ActionListener

Comment: Oh, sorry, thought it was in the for-loop...so now the code won't compile instead :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes but it is seperate, ActionListener must be instantiated first before he add the listener buttons.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the `ActionListener` is been declared before the `JButton` array.

Instead, declare `buttons` as a instance variable...

```
 public class SomeClass extends ... {
     private JButton[] buttons;
```

Then you should be able to reference `buttons` in your `ActionListener` using

```
if(actionEvent.getSource() == buttons[1]){
```

When constructing your buttons array, you will also need to make sure you are not shadowing your variables, for example...

```
buttons= new JButton[10]; 
for(int i = 0;i < buttons.length;i++){
```

Having said all that, if you want to clean up your code, then I would suggest you take a look at [How to use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html), which provides a re-usable API for actions, which can be attached to buttons, menu items and key bindings