# How to handle keypresses for a calculator made in Java?

Tags: java, netbeans, calculator, keypress

I've made a simple calculator using an tutorial online using Netbeans and it works fine when clicking the respective buttons, however I'm looking to improve it by allowing keypresses to work.

What I'd like is for the numbers 0-9 to work, +, -, *, / and enter as =.

I think I know how to do it, but can't seem to figure it out.

For example, the code for my 1 button is:

```
private void btnOneActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    String btnOneText = txtDisplay.getText() + btnOne.getText();
    txtDisplay.setText(btnOneText);
}
```

So for the keypress I created a keypress event but I'm not sure what the code is. I assume it's something like this:

```
private void jPanel1KeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                   
    //if statement to check if 1 key has been pressed, then execute rest of code
    String btnOneText = txtDisplay.getText() + btnOne.getText();
    txtDisplay.setText(btnOneText);
}
```

However I'm probably completely wrong. Any help?

Comment: Don't use a KeyListener. Instead you should be using Key Bindings and Actions. Check out this simplified [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21434873/setting-up-keylisteners-using-the-mvc-in-java/21436635#21436635).

Comment: Whenever I try to add the imports for that I'm getting an error on my package jCalculator and the program won't run. Where exactly am I meant to be adding that code? I realise this comment is fairly ambiguous.

Comment: @DivineShine: all imports go at the top in the same place. If you're seeing problems using imports, show the offending code and the error messages please.

Comment: @Hovercraft once I add the imports I get an error next to my
    package jCalculator
Stating class, interface or enum expected.

Comment: This will give you some place to start - http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=2nk4rZgqdu0#t=370

Comment: The example I proved can be cut/paste/compiled and executed. Understand the concepts of the code provided and then incorporate the knowledge into your code by creating your own Actions and Key Bindings. The example doesn't use a package so I don't know what you have done to the code.

Comment: @camickr I already have my own code using a package, with buttons etc drawn out with code behind them, so the KeyListening example you pasted was helpful to learn, but hasn't helped in what I've already created. I think I'll just stick to what I've made for now, thanks for the help all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either of KeyListener or KeyBindings depending on your usage.

Since you are designing a simple calculator, there is no harm with KeyListener since there are not many controls.

Demo code for the same is.

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
      switch( keyCode ) {

   case KeyEvent.VK_0:
       //handle 0 press
       break;
   case KeyEvent.VK_1:
       // handle 1 press
       break;
   case KeyEvent.VK_2:
       // handle 2 press
       break;
   case KeyEvent.VK_3 :
       // handle 3 press
       break;
   //
 }
}
```

You can find the keycodes here : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html